# Case When Exist across 2 table (and 3 columns) in a select statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi all you awesome SQL people

I'm moving data from a live database into a temp reporting database (soon to be a DW).

I came across a data integrity issue which I'm struggling to clean up.

The following table (from the source db) are involved:

  [Packaging and Sizes]: this contains product info.

  [Sales Journal]: This contains the sales of the products.

What it should do:

---

1. If there is a ***[Sales Journal].[Pack Code]*** and it does exist in the product table it should return ***[Sales Journal].[Pack Code]***.
2. If there is NOT a ***[Sales Journal].[Pack Code]*** and the ***[Sales Journal].[Product Code]*** does exist in the product table it should return ***[Sales Journal].[Product Code]***.
3. If the ***[Sales Journal].[Pack Code]*** and the ***[Sales Journal].[Product Code]*** does not exist in the **[Packaging and Sizes]** table (***[Packaging and Sizes].[Product Code]***) it should return 0.

Problem:

---

Currently, point 3 returns the ***[Sales Journal].[Product Code]*** instead of 0 if the product does not exist.

Question(s):

---

  Where am I making the mistake and how can I get the results I want?

Here is my actual code, but the part in question is the CASE expression:

```
SELECT CONVERT( CHAR(8), [Date & Time], 112) AS DateID,
       CONVERT( TIME, [Date & Time]) AS [Time],
       --,CASE WHEN ISNULL([Pack Code],'') = '' THEN [Product Code] ELSE [Pack Code] END AS [ProductCode] <-- Old line 
       CASE
           WHEN ISNULL([Pack Code], '') = ''
           THEN CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT ps.[Product Code]
                        FROM [Packaging and Sizes] ps
                        WHERE [Product Code] = ps.[Product Code]
                    )
                    THEN [Product Code]
                    ELSE '0'
                END
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT ps.[Product Code]
                        FROM [Packaging and Sizes] ps
                        WHERE [Pack Code] = ps.[Product Code]
                    )
                    THEN [Pack Code]
                    ELSE CASE
                             WHEN EXISTS
                             (
                                 SELECT ps.[Product Code]
                                 FROM [Packaging and Sizes] ps
                                 WHERE [Product Code] = ps.[Product Code]
                             )
                             THEN [Product Code]
                             ELSE '0'
                         END
                END
       END AS [ProductCode],
       [Quantity],
       [Pack Size],
       [Landed Cost],
       [Sales Tax],
       [Line Total],
       [Transaction Tracking Number]
FROM [Sales Journal]
```

PS. This will be used in and insert into the reporting database.

Sample Data:

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Packaging and Sizes](
    [Link Code] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Product Code] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Base Product] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Packaging and Sizes] ([Link Code],[Product Code],[Base Product])
     VALUES('100001','100001',1)
     VALUES('100002','100002',1)
     VALUES('100003','100003',1)
     VALUES('100005','100005',1)
     VALUES('100007','600100003',0)
     VALUES('100007','100007',1)
     VALUES('100008','100008',1)
     VALUES('100008','600100066',0)
     VALUES('100009','100009',1)
     VALUES('100010','100010',1)
     VALUES('100010','600100022',0)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales Journal](
    [Line Number] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date & Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [User Number] [smallint] NULL,
    [Account Number] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Product Code] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Pack Code] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [Department Number] [smallint] NULL,
    [Quantity] [real] NULL,
    [Pack Size] [real] NULL,
    [Landed Cost] [real] NULL,
    [Sales Tax] [real] NULL,
    [Discount] [real] NULL,
    [Dicount Value] [real] NULL,
    [Line Total] [real] NULL,
    [Transaction Tracking Number] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [Branch Number] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Discount Type] [tinyint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales Journal]
           ([Date & Time],[User Number],[Account Number],[Product Code],[Pack Code],
           [Department Number],[Quantity],[Pack Size],[Landed Cost],[Sales Tax],[Discount],
           [Dicount Value],[Line Total],[Transaction Tracking Number],[Branch Number],[Discount Type])
     VALUES (42728.4482870023,0,'','100001','600100001',1239,1,1,20.553,3.560175,0,0,28.99,1.002,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4486573727,0,'','100002','',1237,1,1,8.114,1.350877,0,0,11,1.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4499883912,0,'','100003','',1071,1,1,9.2879,2.086491,0,0,16.99,2.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4499999653,0,'','100003','',1071,1,1,9.2879,2.086491,0,0,16.99,2.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4500346875,0,'','100004','',1038,1,1,3.6978,0.8584211,0,0,6.99,2.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4500462963,0,'','100004','',1038,1,1,3.6978,0.8584211,0,0,6.99,2.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4515045949,0,'','100005','',1059,1,1,7.0653,1.595263,0,0,12.99,3.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4515624653,0,'','100006','600100002',1239,1,1,18.298,3.191754,0,0,25.99,3.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4515740741,0,'','100006','600100002',1239,1,1,18.298,3.191754,0,0,25.99,3.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4525578704,0,'','100007','600100003',1239,1,1,20.5512,3.192982,0,0,26,4.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4526735764,0,'','100008','',1210,1,1,9.5291,2.147895,0,0,17.49,4.003,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4543055556,0,'','100009','',1189,1,1,5.5,0,0,0,9.99,2.002,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4543170949,0,'','100010','',1189,1,1,5.5,0,0,0,9.99,2.002,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4543518519,0,'','100010','600100004',1078,1,1,2.3,0.49,0,0,3.99,2.002,1,0)
     VALUES (42728.4543633912,0,'','100010','600100022',1078,1,1,2.3,0.49,0,0,3.99,2.002,1,0)

GO
```

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML, your current output and desired output.

Comment: Desired Output:

100004 => 0,
100006 => 0,
600100002 => 0,
600100001 => 100001,
100010 => 100010,
600100004 => 100010,
600100022 => 600100022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `COALESCE` statement, with 2 `LEFT JOIN` on the [Packagings and Sizes] table, like:

```
SELECT
       COALESCE(packCode.[Product Code], prodCode.[Product Code], 0) AS [ProductCode]
FROM [Sales Journal] sj
LEFT JOIN [Packaging and Sizes] packCode ON sj.[Pack Code] = packCode.[Product Code]
LEFT JOIN [Packaging and Sizes] prodCode ON sj.[Product Code] = prodCode.[Product Code]
```

It either JOINs it with PackCode, or ProductCode, or return 0 if any of this is found.

Comment: Looks like it's working! When I first tried COALESCE I only had one JOIN on [Packaging and Sizes] so it did not work. Awesome thanks, will do some check to make sure the results are correct just in case.